# Who can be considered a better warrior Arjuna or karan in mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, arjuna, karna

Karna and arjuna are the two greatest warriors of the  mahabharat,there have been often many debates on this topic,But is there any refrences in Mahabharat which show that a particular character like bhisma saying that this warrior is greater than that or who can be consider more greater warrior are there any examples in mahabharata?

Comment: Karna was better than Arjuna because Arjuna wasn't able to defeat Karna. Karna got killed by curse of Parshurama. Besides Karna once fire Vaishnav astra on Arjuna and he didn't had answer of Vaishnav astra of Karna. At that time Krishna saved Arjuna from Karna's astra, else Arjuna was dead that time. Hence Karna was better.

Comment: There were greater warriors such as Bhishma, Drona, Bhagadatta, Bhurisravas etc. The two you mention are not the greatest warriors. They are very popular though.

Comment: Bhishma, Drona, Bhagadatta and Bhurisravas are all weak just like karna. The greatest warrior is Arjuna.

Comment: karna never had Vaishnava Astra. Arjuna defeated karna many times, but karn never defeated Arjuna.